# split log files in same folder as log file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use powershell to split up huge log files into separate files so I can view them. I found some code online to get me started and I modified to fit my needs now I am just fine tuning it. The issue I have is I would like the script in a folder separate than the log file but have the split files be created in the same folder as the log file. Currently it splits the log files in the same folder the script is in. I tried doing the `set-location(split-path $filename -parent -resolve)` which changes the directory to the folder the log file is in but still spits out the split log files into the folder where the script is. Any help will be greatly appreciated Thanks.

```
 #split test
param (
[string] $filename = $null
)
$sw = new-object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$sw.Start()
$rootName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($filename)
$ext = [io.path]::GetExtension($filename)
$linesperFile = 100000#100k
$filecount = 1
$reader = $null
Set-Location(split-path $filename -parent -resolve)
try{
$reader = [io.file]::OpenText($filename)
try{
    "Creating file number $filecount"
    $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}-{1}{2}" -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext))
    $filecount++
    $linecount = 0

    while($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
        "Reading $linesperFile"
        while( ($linecount -lt $linesperFile) -and ($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true)){
            $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine());
            $linecount++
        }

        if($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
            "Closing file"
            $writer.Dispose();

            "Creating file number $filecount"
            $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}-{1}{2}" -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext))
            $filecount++
            $linecount = 0
        }
    }
} finally {
    $writer.Dispose();
}
} finally {
$reader.Dispose();
}
$sw.Stop()

Write-Host "Split complete in " $sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds "seconds"
```

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32379304/4424236) for this question: [split text file into smaller files based on size (windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360801/split-text-file-into-smaller-files-based-on-size-windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET methods (like `File.CreateText()` for example), resolves partial paths relative to the Working Directory of the *process* running, rather than the PowerShell-specific location set by `Set-Location`.

Create an absolute path with `Join-Path` and pass that to `CreateText()` instead:

```
$newFileName = '{0}-{1}{2}' -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext)
$fullPath    = Join-Path -Path (Split-Path $filename -Parent) -ChildPath $newFileName
$writer      = [IO.File]::CreateText($fullPath)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on how .NET methods resolve the path it was helpful and your code worked as intended Thank you.