# ORACLE 11G Data Downloading

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I’m using Toad for Oracle to access 11G environment and my dataset has 1,000,000 records. While downloading I want to split the files in 100,000 each 10 files. I do not have the authority to create tables instead I can run and download only. Is their a way I can split the files while downloading?

[image: Data Downloader Image]

Comment: I don't see any such option in toad export

Comment: Goolgle for "toad automation designer".

Answer (score 0):

You can split a text file using PowerShell or linux shell.

[How to Split Large Text File into Smaller Files in Linux](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/split-large-text-file-smaller-files-linux/)

- example for linux

  #split -l 100000 test.txt new
- example for Windows

[How can I split a text file using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001776/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-using-powershell)

```
split_log.ps1
    param(
    [string]$input_file = "",
    [string]$count_line = ""
    )
    $lineCount = 0
    $fileCount = 1

    foreach ($line_file in get-content $input_file)
    {
        write $line_file | out-file -encoding ASCII -Append $input_file"_"$fileCount".out"
        $lineCount++

        if ($lineCount -eq $count_line)
        {
            $fileCount++
            $lineCount = 0
        }
    }




       PS C:\АСУ\Stackoverflow\split_log> ls


    Каталог: C:\АСУ\Stackoverflow\split_log


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        17.12.2018      6:03   10959355 1124.sql
-a---        17.12.2018      7:27        357 split_log.ps1


PS C:\АСУ\Stackoverflow\split_log> .\split_log.ps1 .\1124.sql 10000
PS C:\АСУ\Stackoverflow\split_log> ls


    Каталог: C:\АСУ\Stackoverflow\split_log


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        17.12.2018      6:03   10959355 1124.sql
-a---        17.12.2018      7:50    2461667 1124.sql_1.out
-a---        17.12.2018      7:50    2461458 1124.sql_2.out
-a---        17.12.2018      7:50    2461340 1124.sql_3.out
-a---        17.12.2018      7:50    2461352 1124.sql_4.out
-a---        17.12.2018      7:50    1113540 1124.sql_5.out
-a---        17.12.2018      7:27        357 split_log.ps1
```

Comment: I’m new to PowerShell.... I have the text file on my Desktop and I want to split the files in a way the header also populates. Could you help me with the code?