# copy lines 5 to 10 in a .txt file to another .txt file

Tags: powershell

I have a very large .txt file (6GB) that I need to break into several files.  I'd like to run a powershell script that would copy lines 1 to 100,000 to a new file, then run it again for lines 100,001 to 200,000 and so on.  I'm not a developer and I've been unable to figure out the syntax to get the job done.  Any help will be appreciated.

I've tried with both Get-Content and Get-ChildItem

```
Get-Content C:\Users\alind\Downloads\2018\in.txt [5..10] | Set-Content C:\Users\alind\Downloads\2018\mid.txt
```

I'm looking for lines 6 to 11 in the file in.txt to be copied into the file mid.txt.

Comment: The microsoft docs has an example of doing things like this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split a text file using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001776/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-using-powershell)

Comment: mhhollomon, that is page I'm trying to decipher.  For example, I can get lines 1 to 100.  However, I don't see how to get lines 10 to 20.

Comment: For your sample line put the Get-Content comdlet in parentheses: `(Get-Content C:\Users\alind\Downloads\2018\in.txt)[5..10] | Set-Content C:\Users\alind\Downloads\2018\mid.txt` but that won't work for your giant file.

Comment: LotPings, thank you!  Your first suggestion is different than what I was looking to do, but the end result gives me just what I need.  I tried putting the parenthesis in the command line and it works on my small test file.  Why won't it work on the giant file?

Comment: `Get-Content in.txt | Select-Object -Skip 5 -First 6 | Set-Content out.txt`

Comment: @Andrew Well it depends on your memory, the parentheses forces to read in the whole file first. Ansgar and Andrei showed you alternatives. To have someone recognize your comment address him/her with an @ in front.

Comment: @LotPings, Thank you all for the input and instruction.  I'm testing the solutions provided now and will post back.  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReadCount` parameter of the `Get-Content` cmdlet may help.

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Users\alind\Downloads\2018\in.txt -ReadCount 100000 |
ForEach-Object -Begin { $i = 0 } -Process {
    Set-Content -Path ('C:\Users\alind\Downloads\2018\in{0:d8}.txt' -f ++$i) -Value $_
  }
```

Comment: Thank  you.  It worked perfectly and very fast on a smaller 67mb file.  I'm testing now on a larger file.

Comment: Again, thank you.  Although the other solutions worked, this one finished faster, so it is the one I'm using going forward.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you.