# Powershell - How can I split a simple text file and overwrite the original

Tags: powershell, split

Let's say i have a text file (file.txt) with this in it:  `something.ab-cdefgh-jk-lmno-1.pqr-stuv-a.z.something-xy.somethingelse` 
I want to overwrite the file to look like this instead: `something.ab-cdefgh-jk-lmno-1`

I've tried a few things with split but I'm a powershell noob and I don't think I'm doing it right. I've tried to follow along with [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001776/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-using-powershell) but I can't seem to understand how to apply it to my question. As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

A little more info:  In my script I hit an API to generate a file with a string. The API doesn't provide a way to split the result or alter it. The file I end up with is a single string with a bunch of stuff I don't want. I just want the stuff before the second period.

Comment: If you want to have a file with a particular content why don't you simply create a new file with this particular content? If that's not what you want to achieve you may elaborate more detailed what your challenge is. And please show your code.

Comment: So you have `[WORDS]`.`[WORDS]`.`[IGNORE REST]` correct?

Comment: Hi @Olaf. In my script I hit an API to generate a file with a string. The API doesn't provide a way to split the result or alter it. The file I end up with is a single string with a bunch of stuff I don't want. I just want the stuff before the second period. I don't usually work on Windows things so something simple like this has proven difficult.

Comment: Yes @Drew. That's correct.

Comment: @Kryten You should update your question with that information. At the moment people willing to hlep you get the wrong idea. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Olaf. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you explained this in your comments, its a fairly simple split and join.

```
$content = 'something.ab-cdefgh-jk-lmno-1.pqr-stuv-a.z.something-xy.somethingelse'
$content = ($content -split '\.')[0..1] -join '.'
```

The `[0..1]` will take the first and second part of the array, then it does a `-join '.'` to put just those two bits back together.
The `-split '\.'` needs the `\` to escape the `.` as `-split` accepts regular expressions (Regex)

Comment: Thank you much for explaining it. I understand the split a lot better now. I'll test it out and let you know if that did the trick.

Comment: For a non-Regex split you can use the `[string]` class's `.Split()` method. `$content.Split('.')[0..1] -join '.'` ...or if you're using Regex you could just get the string in one go without having to split and join with `$content -replace '(?<=^[^.]+\.[^.]*)\..*'`