# Splitting .txt file in half

Tags: windows

I have a large assortment of .txt files. All of them look somehat like this:

1.txt:

```
Title
Title info
Data;DataB;DataC
10;20;30
20;40;50
10;60;70
```

I was wondering is there a command in Windows that takes all .txt files in a folder and splits each of them into two seperate .txt files at a specified line? Kind of like this as output:

1A.txt:

```
Title
Title info
Data;DataB;DataC
10;20;30
```

1B.txt:

```
20;40;50
10;60;70
```

Thank you very much for your answers.

Sincerest regards, and have a nice day.

Comment: Maybe this answer to a similar question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23061293/15059132